# Using infowindowclicklistener for maker pin in google maps for data retrieved from JSON android

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

I am working on a project where there is a google map and the marker pins in it are populated with data recieved from JSON.I have set the marker pins as follows:

```
public void loadpinsonmap()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<job_list.size();i++)
        {
            Job_data j=job_list.get(i);
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(j.job_shop_name+"@@@"+j.job_total_price)
                    .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(j.job_shop_latitude),Double.parseDouble(j.job_shop_longitude))));



        }
    }
```

The custom info window is set as follows:

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

                @Override
                public View getInfoWindow(Marker pin) {

                    View v = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                    TextView tvshop = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop_name);


                    TextView tvprice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_job_price);

                    String[] contents = pin.getTitle().split("@@@");
                    String shop_name = contents[0];
                    String job_price = contents[1];
                    tvshop.setText(shop_name);
                    tvprice.setText("Rs "+job_price);
                    return v;


                }

                @Override
                public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                    return null;
                }
            });
```

Now my issue is this:

I want to click the info window and get the corresponding object for that particular marker pin.One way of doing it would be to iterate through the list and compare with the latitude of that particular pin's latitude.But if the list is large then there would be time wasted in iteration.So is there any way to get the corrseponding object other than iterating through the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try OnMarkerClickListener

```
/**
 * This method is get called when user tap on a marker
 */
private OnMarkerClickListener mMarkerClickListener = new OnMarkerClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "clicked: " + markersAndObjects.get(marker.getId()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
};

// Don't forget to set the listener 

googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mMarkerClickListener);

// markersAndObjects below is a hashmap where 

Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
markersAndObjects.put(marker.getId(), (YOUR DATA));
```

Comment: So you want me to avoid using setInfoWindowAdapter for the custom info window?

Comment: I want to write click event for the infowindow not for the marker pin.

Comment: Put the data on a hashmap, rather than list as above , assign a unique id as key for info window. You u can avoid iteration